# How to serve an image as a stream

Tags: php, node.js, image, server, streaming

I've noticed in my many years of using the web (and occasionally developing websites) that there are some website that serve images differently than others.

1. The first kind serves a low quality image first then gradually serve more data so that the image becomes clearer.
2. The second kind serves the image as if it's being scanned vertically top to bottom.

This image illustrates what i'm trying to say [image]

As far as I can remember, every PHP, NodeJS server that i have ever set serves images like the second kind.

***So my question is how can I achieve behavior 1 in PHP or NodeJS (with ExpressJS) ?***

**PS**:

> There is no javascript/ajax/(any 3rd party library being used)
>
> The websites that i have noticed this thing on are not using JS/multiple request to achieve this. It's all purely server side.

Comment: You have to create the image file with interlacing (as opposed to progressive scan) to get the effect you want https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interlacing_(bitmaps) This has nothing to do with how the image is served

Comment: The first file is not being "streamed" it is a "Progressive JPEG" file as opposed to the second which is a "baseline" JPEG file.

Comment: If you want to convert a JPEG image into interlaced in PHP, there's this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41732652/convert-jpeg-to-a-progressive-jpeg-in-php

Answer (score 0):

For the fisrt point , you can use image magick of PHP ,

```
$im = new imagick();
$im->setResolution(200,200);
$im->readImage('path to the image');
$im->writeImage('path to store the new image with name of image and extension'); 
$im->clear(); 
$im->destroy();
```

> You need to set Resolution before  read the image. and then repeat the script depend on your use cases .

Hope that help you .